# Matplotlib cannot find facefile, is using old Python interpreter location

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've a script that utilised the Matplotlib library, the script works fine at home and in the Uni labs, but I have an issue when I try and run it on my work machine.

Originally, I was running the interpreter from my USB stick - no problems there - but I've recently copied the interpreter to the hard drive to save messing around, and now if I run the script *without* my USB stick in I get the following critical error (with spacing added for readability):

```
# lots of Traceback trimmed off here

File "d:\Python2.6.5\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", 
line 221, in _get_agg_font
  font = FT2Font(str(fname))

RuntimeError: Could not open facefile F:\Apps\Python2.6.5\lib\site-packages\
matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\Vera.ttf; Cannot_Open_Resource
```

As you would expect, it will work fine if I connect my USB stick with the interpreter on it.

Clearly somewhere, the library has a configuration somewhere that points it to the old USB location.
**Where is this configuration data kept and/or how do I fix this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

matplotlib keeps it's config file in the .matplotlib directory [finding the location of the directory](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/faq/troubleshooting_faq.html#locating-matplotlib-config-dir)

Change the [MPLCONFIGDIR](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/faq/environment_variables_faq.html#envvar-MPLCONFIGDIR) environment variable to change the directory location.

Comment: Ah ha, that's it -- running `matplotlib.get_configdir()` gave me the location `C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\.matplotlib` (WinXP), and removing the `fontList.cache` file solved the problem.

Comment: On my Fedora, the path was `/home/username/.config/matplotlib`. The `matplotlib` folder was empty.

Comment: Well, this answer did not really solve my problem. As in my previous comment, the .matplotlib folder was inexisting. Matplotlib was globally installed using pip. The font file is located in `/usr/share/fonts/` and should be globally accessible.